# How iOS HTML5 video player detects a file type?

Tags: ios, html, video, playback

Now i am implementing a video playback on my site and for mobile devices i use HTML 5 video player:

```
<video src="/get_video.php/myfile.mov" controls width="400" height="250"></video>
```

In `src` attribute stored url to `php` file which output a contents of video file. MIME-type of file i don't know(it's dynamic) so i send content type header - `application/octet-stream`.

And my iPhone cant play this video: [screenshot](http://s3.micp.ru/JS8sb.jpg)

So Question: How to force the player to play videos?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend reading these resources on Video tags:

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_src.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/video

As I understand, you have to specify in your MIME type a real video type (vs `application/octet-stream`). You mentioned that it's dynamic, however on the server side you know which file are you reading (so, you can figure out file format).

Supported types are:

- `video/mp4`
- `video/webm`
- `video/ogg`